# How to run unity next on a virtualbox?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, ubuntu-touch, 13.04, hud

I have 12.04 running as my main OS. I only have Ubuntu, so I can not afford to screw it up. I installed 13.04 on a virtualbox and compiled and install unity-next to try it. When I ran it from inside the unity desktop, virtualbox crashed. One of my installations completely broke Ubuntu 13.04, so I had to even reinstall it.

To find out the problem I used xinit to login and when I ran the unity/unit-next/run, following message showed up. Is it possible to run unity-next on virtualbox. Is there some changes I need to make to run it. Does upgrading the virtualbox helps. Below is the log from terminal.

```
Module 'HudClient' does not contain a module identifier directive - it cannot be protected from external registrations.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
username@username-VirtualBox:~/unity/unity-next$ ./run
Module 'HudClient' does not contain a module identifier directive - it cannot be protected from external registrations.
QObject::connect: No such signal Lenses::roleNamesChanged(QHash<int,QByteArray>) in /home/username/unity/unity-next/plugins/Utils/qsortfilterproxymodelqml.cpp:73
received a sourceModel that does not notify of changes of its roleNames 

** (process:2492): WARNING **: Could not make client connection: [GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method `CreateQuery']

** (process:2492): CRITICAL **: hud_client_query_constructed: assertion `hud_client_connection_new_query(cquery->priv->connection, cquery->priv->query, &path, &results, &appstack)' failed
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Shell.qml:189: TypeError: Cannot call method 'unfocusCurrentApplication' of undefined
NOTICE: The Ubuntu.Application plugin was not found, so all window management is emulated in this application.
This emulation will not be perfect, you *must* not trust it. To be safe always test on a device with Ubuntu.Application available.
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Shell.qml:444:13: QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onSideStageFocusedApplicationChanged"
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Shell.qml:444:13: QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onMainStageFocusedApplicationChanged"
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Hud/HudParametrizedActionsPage.qml:138:5: QML Item: Binding loop detected for property "width"
Fail to load themed icon for: "audio-volume-high" 
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Panel/IndicatorItem.qml:48:9: QML QQuickImage: Failed to get image from provider: image://gicon/audio-volume-high
Fail to load themed icon for: "wifi-none" 
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Panel/IndicatorItem.qml:48:9: QML QQuickImage: Failed to get image from provider: image://gicon/wifi-none
Fail to load themed icon for: "audio-volume-high" 
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Panel/Menus/Overview/OverviewGrid.qml:58:17: QML QQuickImage: Failed to get image from provider: image://gicon/audio-volume-high
Fail to load themed icon for: "wifi-none" 
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Panel/Menus/Overview/OverviewGrid.qml:58:17: QML QQuickImage: Failed to get image from provider: image://gicon/wifi-none
OpenGL Warning: glFlushVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glVertexArrayRangeNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerOutputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameteriNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glCombinerParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinalCombinerInputNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetCombinerOutputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterfvNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFinalCombinerInputParameterivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glDeleteFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glFinishFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGenFencesNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glGetFenceivNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glIsFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glSetFenceNV not found in mesa table
OpenGL Warning: glTestFenceNV not found in mesa table
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0x24784f0, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0x24784f0, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0x24784f0, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0x24784f0, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0x24784f0, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0x24784f0, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0x24784f0, failed to get XVisualInfo
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x24784f0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0x8002 returned 0 visuals
OpenGL Warning: glXGetFBConfigAttrib for 0x24784f0, failed to get XVisualInfo
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
OpenGL Warning: glXChooseFBConfig returning NULL, due to attrib=0xc, next=0x18
OpenGL Warning: glXChooseFBConfig returning NULL, due to attrib=0xc, next=0x18
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Components/CrossFadeImage.qml:39: Unable to assign QSize to QSizeF
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Components/CrossFadeImage.qml:39: Unable to assign QSize to QSizeF
__showHeader is deprecated. Do not use it.
QObject::connect: No such signal QQuickListModel::roleNamesChanged(QHash<int,QByteArray>) in /home/username/unity/unity-next/plugins/Utils/qsortfilterproxymodelqml.cpp:73
received a sourceModel that does not notify of changes of its roleNames 
QObject::connect: No such signal QQuickListModel::roleNamesChanged(QHash<int,QByteArray>) in /home/username/unity/unity-next/plugins/Utils/qsortfilterproxymodelqml.cpp:73
received a sourceModel that does not notify of changes of its roleNames 
QObject::connect: No such signal QQuickListModel::roleNamesChanged(QHash<int,QByteArray>) in /home/username/unity/unity-next/plugins/Utils/qsortfilterproxymodelqml.cpp:73
received a sourceModel that does not notify of changes of its roleNames 
QObject::connect: No such signal QQuickListModel::roleNamesChanged(QHash<int,QByteArray>) in /home/username/unity/unity-next/plugins/Utils/qsortfilterproxymodelqml.cpp:73
received a sourceModel that does not notify of changes of its roleNames 
WARN  2013-04-04 18:07:57 unity.glib.dbus.proxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:418 Calling method "Search" on object path: "/com/canonical/unity/lens/people" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.canonical.Unity.Lens.People was not provided by any .service files
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Dash/DashMusic.qml:94: ReferenceError: root is not defined
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Components/OpenEffect.qml:27: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Dash/DashPeople.qml:118: ReferenceError: root is not defined
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Components/OpenEffect.qml:27: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
file:///home/username/unity/unity-next/Dash/DashVideos.qml:142: ReferenceError: root is not defined
WARN  2013-04-04 18:07:57 unity.glib.dbus.proxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:418 Calling method "InfoRequest" on object path: "/com/canonical/unity/lens/mockmusic" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `com.canonical.Unity.Lens' on object at path /com/canonical/unity/lens/mockmusic
WARN  2013-04-04 18:07:57 unity.glib.dbus.proxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:418 Calling method "SetViewType" on object path: "/com/canonical/unity/lens/mockmusic" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `com.canonical.Unity.Lens' on object at path /com/canonical/unity/lens/mockmusic
WARN  2013-04-04 18:07:57 unity.glib.dbus.proxy GLibDBusProxy.cpp:418 Calling method "Search" on object path: "/com/canonical/unity/lens/mockmusic" failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `com.canonical.Unity.Lens' on object at path /com/canonical/unity/lens/mockmusic
^CNumber of leaked pixmaps: 84
i
```